# Factory Girl with polymorphic has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

I'm trying to set up a factorygirl has_many association with a polmorphic association, using the new syntax. Here is the code. It isn't properly building the address, and associating it with the site.

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :addressee, :polymorphic => true

end

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many addresses, :as => :addressee, :dependent => :destroy

end

***** FACTORYGIRL ******


FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :address, class: 'Address' do
        property_type "House"
        street_number "31"
        street_type "STREET"
        suburb "XXXXX"
        postcode "XXXX"
    end

    factory :site_address, class: 'Address' do
        property_type "House"
        street_number "31"
        street_type "STREET"
        suburb "XXXX"
        postcode "XXXX"
        site
    end
end


FactoryGirl.define do

    factory :site, class: 'Site' do
        name "MyString"
        organisation_category nil
        service_type_organisation_category_id 1
        telephone "MyString"
        fax "MyString"
        email "MyString"
        url "MyString"
        clinical_software_package_id 1
        billing_software_package_id 1
        bulk_billing false
        disabled_access false
        ncacch false
        parking false
        organisation nil

        factory :site_with_addresses do
            ignore do
                address_count 1
            end

            after (:create) do |site,evaluator|
                FactoryGirl.create_list(:site_address, evaluator.address_count, addressee: site)
            end
        end

    end


end
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't declared the association within the factory for address, try

```
factory :address, class: 'Address' do
    property_type "House"
    street_number "31"
    street_type "STREET"
    suburb "XXXXX"
    postcode "XXXX"
    association :addressee, :factory => :site
end
```

See https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations for more details about how to customise your associations

Comment: I guess that won't work. Because he doesn't have factory called `addressee`. `If the factory name is the same as the association name`

Comment: Hey guys,

https://gist.github.com/emilevictor/a376231cf11345b35e1b

Here's the factorygirl source for my sites factory. I thought that I had included it, but I accidentally included the :address factory instead. The relevant code is :site_address and :site.

The current method that I am using (as shown on the site) is wrong.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. It seems that FactoryGirl understands that `:addressee` is a polymorphic association and it correctly sets both the `:addressee_id` and `:addressee_type` properties of the Address object.

Answer (score -1):

This gist may help - https://gist.github.com/travisr/2830535/

```
class Alert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :alertable, :polymorphic => true
end


class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :alerts, :as => :alertable
end


FactoryGirl.define do
  Factory.define :alert do |alert|
    alert.alertable { |a| a.association(:region) }
  end
end
```